# How do I use the card fingerprint feature of Stripe's API via their Python library?

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments

According to https://support.stripe.com/questions/blocking-certain-card-numbers , a particular card can be blocked from being charged based on its fingerprint.

I haven't been able to find any example code that would allow me to do that.

I am working with Flask and would like to check a card's fingerprint against a table that would store cards/fingerprints that are banned.

Has anyone done this with Stripe's Python library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this, I would look at the `Token.card.fingerprint` property of a [token](https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#token_object) and compare that to your table of blocked fingerprints.

Answer (score 1):

You will look at Token.card.fingerprint property of a token. 
A card is a object and a fingureprint field available only live environment.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#create_card_token